# Nested Objects with Inherited Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, inherited-resources

First off, I love inherited_resources

Consider the following:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inputs, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :output
end

class JobsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
end
```

When I request jobs/1.json I just get the JSON of the job object.  What  I want is also the inputs and output to be included.  I normally achieve this by:

`job.to_json(include: [:inputs,:output])`

My question is what is the best way to achieve this with IR?  For now, I'll just overwrite show, but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant way?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can override job's to_json in the model so when IR calls it, you'll get the input and output along with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@corroded put me on the right track.  The answer is to overwrite as_json on the model.

Specifically I did the following:

```
  public

  def as_json(options={})
    super(include: [:inputs,:output])
  end
```